# JGraphT Library how to access the vertices of an edge

Tags: java, routes, jgrapht

I have a function that return a list of edges But I want to access the vertices of the edges.

DijkstraShortestPath.findPathBetween(graph, start,end) this is the function that returns the list of edges.

I want to access the vertices of each edge.

I tried to search for a way to do it but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4):

If you have all edges you could use the methods mentioned here:
http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/Graph.html

Taken from the API:

```
V getEdgeSource(E e)

//Returns the source vertex of an edge. For an undirected graph, source and target are distinguishable designations (but without any mathematical meaning).

    Parameters:
        e - edge of interest 
    Returns:
        source vertex


V getEdgeTarget(E e)

    //Returns the target vertex of an edge. For an undirected graph, source and target are distinguishable designations (but without any mathematical meaning).

    Parameters:
        e - edge of interest 
    Returns:
        target vertex
```

So for every Edge you got in the list, just get the source/target vertex